# Strange behavior w/ strlen() in boolean expression

Tags: c++, expression, boolean-expression, strlen

Today I was trying to debug an application and I found a strange behavior of a boolean expression that contains strlen().

Here follows a simple code that reproduces the issue.

```
char test[20] = "testTestTest";  //the length is 12
bool b = 0 < (9 - strlen(test)); //should be false (0 < -3) = false
```

at the end of the execution b is true but it should be false.

Saving the result of strlen() in a variable works.

```
char test[20] = "testTestTest"; //the length is 12
int length = strlen(test);      //save the length
bool b = 0 < (9 - length);      //should be false (0 < -3) = false
```

at the end of the execution b is false (as it is supposed to be).

**What is the difference between the two implementations?

Why is the first one not working?**

The original affected code was something like this:

```
char test[20] = "testTestTest"; //the length is 12
for(int i = 0; i < (9 - strlen(test)); i++){
    //do something (in my case I do NOT edit the test string)
}
```

the for loop is supposed to be never executed (with strings >= 9) but it actually loops infinitely.

Comment: What's `boolean` actually? That's not a c++ intrinsic type.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It was bool.

Comment: Also, just a tip, never use `strlen` in a loop - it takes O(n) where n is the string size, so you are just making the same operation over and over again, unnecessarily

Comment: Since you are in C++, why not use std::string or std::wstring?

Comment: @Joel This is part of a school project. Using string type was forbidden.

Comment: @GabrielIlharco: If `test` isn't modified inside the loop, `strlen(test)` should be recognized as a loop invariant by the compiler and only be executed once before the loop.

Comment: @Micheal, didn't know that, thanks for the info =)

Comment: @Michael Some compilers do that, but beware: they require special annotations or built-in knowledge about which functions have side effects and which don't. While a compiler may perform this optimisation for `strlen`, it very likely won't perform this same optimisation for custom functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Saving the result of strlen() in a variable works.

Your variable is of a different type than what `strlen()` returns. It's the implicit conversion from `size_t` to `int` that makes it work.

The non-working version typically evaluates `9 - strlen(test)` as `(size_t)9 - strlen(test)`, a very large unsigned number, rather than as `9 - (int)strlen(test)`, a negative signed number.